# Can Varnish Read a List of Backend Hosts from a Text File

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

Is there any way for varnish to read a list of backend urls from a text file, and then proxy cache misses to a random url taken from the text file?

What I imagine is something like this pseudocode...

/var/services/backend-urls.conf

```
http://backend-host-1/path/to/application
http://backend-host-2/path/to/application
http://backend-host-3/path/to/application
# etc
```

varnish config

```
sub vcl_miss {
  // read a list of urls from a text file
  backendHosts = readFile("/var/services/backend-urls.conf");

  //choose a random url from the file
  randomHost = chooseLineAtRandom(backendHosts);

  //proxy the request to the random host
  set req.backend = randomHost;   
}
```

To provide some background, I work on a server system that comprises a number of backend applications that currently sit behind a front-end running apache. We are evaluating replacing the apache layer with varnish so we can benefit from the caching capabilities of varnish. We also have a service discovery framework that knows the endpoint locations for each backend application (the endpoint urls change periodically as new hosts emerge or are taken out of service).

Currently we use the [RewriteMap functionality in mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html) to route requests to the backend services. Then we have a process to maintain the lists of backend services based upon the contents of the service discovery framework.

All this works well for us in apache, except that apache is like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut. All we really want is the reverse proxy loigc, and the caching in varnish would be helpful too.

Is there any way to have varnish read the list of backend urls from an external resource?

Answer (score 0):

Without resorting to custom vmod/c modules, the quick answer is no.
The VCL instruction are being compiled within varnish, and that rules out run-time inclusions.

But why not include within the VCL a separate backend vcl which includes the current backends. 
that vcl file could be written out on demand. Then using varnishadm CLI command you could request a new compile of the VCL, therefore bringing the config live.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two potential solutions.

The first is to have something generate your VCL and backends such as Chef or some custom scripting. You can then process the text file into backend definitions and the necessary VCL to invoke them. To handle the requirement for the random backend you could use a [director](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/reference/vcl.html#directors). I've not dealt with directors myself but it looks like they are meant to solve that requirement. When changes to the backends occur you could rerun the generation script/Chef and tell Varnish to reload its configuration either using `varnishadm` or `service varnish reload` to avoid a full restart.

The second would be to implement it in C, either via a VMOD as Marcel Dumont suggests or possibly using inline C in your VCL.

Answer (score 0):

With [vmod_dynamic](https://github.com/nigoroll/libvmod-dynamic) you can just use any DNS name as a backend or even service records.

For your use case, one option would be to set up an SRV record in DNS pointing to all your servers and then just use that as for example in the [basic-stub.vtc](https://github.com/nigoroll/libvmod-dynamic/blob/master/src/tests/service/basic-stub.vtc) test case.